# How do I pass the variable value of jsp to urls.py?

Tags: jsp

You need to generate tags in jsp. At this time, the value specified in jsp must be included in the tag value. What should I do?

dJango 2.0 > 
Python 3

pp_001.html

aTag = ...

{% url "pp_02_download" id=value %}

Can not send value.

```
$('#dataTables-wkgrid tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
   var data = table.row( this ).data();
   value = data.id  ; 
   aTag = '<a href="{% url "pp_02_download" id=value %}" class="list-group-item">'+data.doc_name
        + "</a>"
})
$('.list-group').html(aTag)
```

urls.py

```
  path('PP/download/<int:id>/' , views_pp.download , name="pp_02_download"),
```

views_pp.py

```
def download(req,id):
    print(id)
    pp_02 = Pp_02.objects.get(id=id)
    filenames = pp_02.file_names
    docname  = pp_02.doc_name

    filename = filenames.name
    print(filename)
```

Reverse for 'pp_02_download' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['crms/PP\/download\/(?P[^/]+)\/$']

---

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the jsp you need to this for example:

```
<a href="hello/hello/edit.do?helloId=${row.id}">Hello</a>
```

where ${row.id} is the value of helloId that is a parameter.

in your case you can do the next:

```
 aTag = '<a href="{% url "pp_02_download" value %}" class="list-group-item">'+data.doc_name
```

you don't need you put id= , if you have more parameters you only need to put in this order separete by ','.

Comment: The variable aTag contains a string value, which is not processed.

__italic__ 
`
$.each(result.filelist,function(index){
   cid       = result.filelist[index].id  ;
   aTag += '<a href="{% url "pp_02_download" ${id} %}" .... </a>'
}
`
** Error..
Could not parse the remainder: '${id}' from '${id}'

Comment: In other words, if we say var i = 100 when using url (), I want to know how to pass 100. And tags are strings, because they must be created dynamically.

Comment: It's possible that you need escape the html to use the aTag option {% autoescape on %}
    {{your aTag }}
{% endautoescape %}